# Debug Boot Sector in Bochs how jmpi works and cpu calculate the instruction address

Tags: assembly, x86, bochs

I encounter several problems when I debug boot sector in bochs.

When debug a boot sector in bochs, bochs debugger first pause in the

```
(0) [0x0000fffffff0] f000:fff0 (unk. ctxt): jmpf 0xf000:e05b      ; ea5be000f0
```

**Q1: Is this instruction `jmpf 0xf000:e05b` the jump instruction in this last 16 byte memory?**

**Q2: What instruction in address `0xf000:e05b`?**

Then we want to let code stop at address 0x7c00

```
<bochs:1> b 0x7c00
<bochs:2> c
(0) Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000007c00 in ?? ()  
Next at t=61419250
(0) [0x000000007c00] 0000:7c00 (unk. ctxt): jmpf 0x07c0:0005   ; ea0500c007
<bochs:3> s                                   
Next at t=61419251
(0) [0x000000007c05] 07c0:0005 (unk. ctxt): mov ax, cs         ; 8cc8
```

These lines of code are generated by `jmpi go,#0x7c00 go: move ax,cx`.

**Q3: instruction `jmpi` is translated into `jmpf` and machine code `ea`, is it right?**

**Q4: 0x0005 is the offset of label go. When does this offset computated? At link time?**

`ea0500c007` is the machine code of jmpf. ea is instruction, 07c0:0005 is the operand (because x86 is litten endian). This code is 5 bytes.

**Q5: How CPU read this instruction and how PC calculate the size of this instruction? Does CPU encounter ea then read next 4 bytes as its operand?**

Answer (score 6):

Q1-Q2. Yes, that's the location where the cpu starts executing after a reset. It is code in ROM that jumps to the BIOS startup code.

Q3. No idea what `jmpi` is, there is no such instruction. It may be a macro defined elsewhere. It seems to generate a far jump.

Q4. The assembler probably calculated that for you if it's in the same module. In a more general case, the linker does that.

Q5. Yes, the cpu decodes the opcode byte(s) to figure out what operands it needs to fetch. When it sees the `ea` it knows to use the next 4 bytes as the target of the jump (in 16 bit mode).